# Simplify multidimensional array in Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-5

I'm returning a collection of data from my controller in my Laravel Applicaiton. However i want to simplify the data so that i can access the properties much easier. This is what i have:

```
"sub_categories": [
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Accounting"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Business"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Engineering"
        }
    ],
]
```

This is what i want to have archived:

```
"sub_categories": [ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Accounting"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Business"
    },  
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Engineering"
    }
]
```

Comment: `$foo = array_map(function($a){return $a[0];}, $foo);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, that worked!

Comment: Rather than manipulating the data you have now, if you posted the code that actually produces this, it may be possible to immediately get it in the structure you want.

Comment: @fubar, thanks for the hint, i felt like it was overkill since the code was a whole lot, but next time i will definitely consider to do that